# Session start php in class

Tags: php

is it possible to start a session in a class method?
The following (that is inside a method of a class) is not working:

```
// some code here
session_start();

// Pass user data to session
$user = new User($row->nif, $row->name);
$_SESSION["user"] = $user;
return $user;
```

When I do, after the session_start:

```
isset($_SESSION);
```

I get false.

*Edit*

Here's my class code

```
class UserDAO {
    private static $AUTHENTICATE_USER_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM pessoa WHERE nif = :username";

    /**
     * Authenticate a user. Returns the authenticated user or null.
     * May throw exceptions.
     * @param type $username
     * @param type $password
     */
        public function authenticateUser($connection, $username, $password) {
        $stmt = $connection->prepare(self::$AUTHENTICATE_USER_QUERY);
        $stmt->bindParam(":username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute(); 

        // Authenticate user
        $rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        foreach($rows as $row) {
            if($row->pin == $password) {
                // Valid user
                session_start();

                // Pass user data to session
                $user = new User($row->nif, $row->name);
                $_SESSION["user"] = $user;
                return $user;
            }
        }

        // Invalid user
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Assert if the user has a session.
     */
    public function isAuthenticated() {
        return session_id() !== '';
    }

    /**
     * Destroy user session.
     */
    public function logoutUser() {
        session_unset(); 
        session_destroy();
    }
}
```

And here's how I'm using it in login.php:

```
$manager = new DBManager();
$userDAO = new UserDAO();

$user = $userDAO->authenticateUser($manager->getConnection(), $username, $password);
```

And in my index.php I have:

```
$userDAO = new UserDAO(); 

if ($userDAO->isAuthenticated()) {
                // The client has a session (so it's authenticated)
                header("Location: home.php");
                exit;
            }
```

Comment: you have to use if(isset($_SESSION["user"]))

Comment: Is session_start(); the first line of your __construct or setter function?

Comment: @michael its a function named authenticateUser

Comment: @user7282 I've tried  session_id() != '' and it also returns false

Comment: give proper code. where you are setting it, where you are outputting it....

Comment: I edited my post with more code

Comment: you need to check whether the program goes inside foreach($rows as $row) {
            if($row->pin == $password) { loops

Comment: It goes, since the login it's working well

Comment: I will not recommend this as in case of object serialization in session, session should get started before class definition loaded. This is not a good practice.